# Domain Service error when called from silverlight

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-mvc-3, domainservices

I am hosting a silverlight app in an existing mvc view.  I am getting the infamous

> "remote server returned an error-> notfound"

when I try to access a domain service defined in the mvc application.
In fiddler I'm getting this error:

> The IControllerFactory 'DrcMvcWeb.Infrastructure.DrcControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'ClientBin'.

Do I need to map a route to the domain service call? This is my first experience with silverlight and RIA services and so far the experience hasn't been good.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's including the ClientBin folder (the location where your SL app is hosted) in the path to the service.  You should be able to use a relative path (from that point) to walk up the tree and back down to your actual service location.  Something like:

```
string urlPath = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../Services/MyService").AbsoluteUri;
```